# how to get MAP key object value in json

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an entity class(entity1) with a Hashmap like this `map<entity2,entity3>` used to map a many to many relationship between 3 tables.
When I return this object of entity1 from my spring controller to javascript the am not able to fetch values in the key object to the map. I am using jquery ajax to call my controller.

I just get all the fields of my entity1 and map as:

```
com.ex.domain.entity2:<object of entity3>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: please post your controller code as well as ajax code that performs the request.